# Piwigo doesn't shows any metadata

Tags: php, server, metadata, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to show and use IPTC data (more precisely, the keywords of a photo) on a Piwigo server installed on a raspberry pi 3.

For doing this, I have precisely followed these tutorials :

- http://fr.piwigo.org/doc/doku.php?id=pwg2:utilisation:fonctionnalites:meta
- http://piwigo.org/doc/doku.php?id=user_documentation:metadata&s[]=iptc

**But when I click the button "show metadata" associated with one of the images of my gallery, it just do absolutely nothing more.**

What I have already tried :

- Restart the server.
- Reinstalling the whole piwigo files.
- Importing images before and after doing the modification of the script.
- The test consisting in testing the tools/sample.jpg file for viewing all included metadata thanks to script tools/metadata.php, is perfectly working : i can see my metadata, so my files are good.

I am getting crazy about this problem!!! 
Do you have any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: up up up up up up

Answer (score 0):

http://piwigo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=116475

You can create file:

```
/local/config/config.inc.php
```

and paste following codes:

```
<?php

/* save file to see change */


$conf['show_exif_fields'] = array(
  'Make',
  'Model',
  'ExifVersion',
  'Software',
  'DateTimeOriginal',
  'FNumber',
  'ExposureBiasValue',
  'FILE;FileSize',
  'ExposureTime',
  'Flash',
  'ISOSpeedRatings',
  'FocalLength',
  'FocalLengthIn35mmFilm',
  'WhiteBalance',
  'ExposureMode',
  'MeteringMode',
  'ExposureProgram',
  'LightSource',
  'Contrast',
  'Saturation',
  'Sharpness',
  );
?>
```

Comment: In order to get a full list of all available EXIF fields (supported by Piwigo) copy an example image to folder `/tools` and rename it to `sample.jpg`. Then you can open page `/tools/metadata.php` with your browser. Piwigo supports only a rather small subset of EXIF.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved installing this plugin:
[read_metadata](https://piwigo.org/ext/extension_view.php?eid=829)

then remember to sync metadata.